# Accessing web.config from a classic asp program

Tags: xml, configuration, asp-classic, config

I have a application in which there is a web.config file. I have to use a classic asp file and I need to access web.config configuration sections with classic asp file.

How can I access the web.config file from a classic asp program?

I find some resouces which was recommending to use a dom parser and access the values with a parser.

Is there a better way?

ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="mykey" value="myvalue"/>

  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I wanna be able to read this config file from a classic asp file. Classic asp file uses **jscript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a .NET class library that loads the XML configuration and exposes the needed properties to COM.

Comment: +1 Among other things, this method lets you minimize exposure to other web.config values (connection string credentials, etc)

Comment: Could you add an example of how to do this?

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to use

```
MyVar = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("myKey")
```

In the code behind to read that value.

Comment: But that's a .NET class. He means classic VBScript ASP.